# Unable to push the elements into empty array using concat

Tags: javascript, es6-class

I tried using `concat` but unable to get array like `[1,2,66]`. By using `push` I got. But using concat is it possible or what is the reason I am not getting the result.

```
const arr = [1, 2, 66];
const data = arr.reduce((obj, k) => { 
            obj.concat(k); 
            return obj 
},[]);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: `concat` [returns a new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). It doesn't mutate the current one. So: `return obj.concat(k)`.

Comment: Thanks got solution. But I need clarification what is the difference I used like return obj and u used return obj.concat(k)

Comment: great for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [concat() method is used to merge two or more arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat). This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead **returns a new array**.

So, `obj.concat(k)` doesn't do anything, and you're returning an *unchanged* `obj` in the next line.

To solve this you can assign the concat to a new variable and return that...

```
const newObj = obj.concat(k);
return newObj;
```

... or simply return the result of the concat:

```
return obj.concat(k);
```

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 66];

const data = arr.reduce((obj, k) => {
  return obj.concat(k);
}, []);

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Speaking of simply: `(obj,k) => obj.concat(k)` is enough.